# Trying to connect to a MariaDB database in google-cloud but cant connect nor show any error report

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb, google-cloud-platform, mysql++

I'm trying to connect a simple program to a `MariaDB` database created in a `VM` in Google Cloud.
The `VM` already has a working installation of `MariaDB` and a small working demo DB.

The code used is the following:

```
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <iostream>

// Nombres
using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlpp;

// INICIO
int main ()
{

    //Declara variables
    char server[]   = "104.197.112.189:3306";
    char user[]     = "root";
    char pass[]     = "xxxxxxxx";
    char db[]       = "resst";
    unsigned int i;

    //conexión
    Connection con;
    con.connect("", server, user, pass);
    con.select_db(db);

    //pedido SQL
    string consulta = "select * from  productos";

    //realización de pedido
    Query pedido = con.query(consulta);
    StoreQueryResult resp = pedido.store();
    Row fila;
    for (i=0;i<resp.num_rows();i++)
        {
            cout << "res " << i+1 << " " << resp[i]["nombre"] << endl;
        }

    con.disconnect();

    return 0;
}
```

This code works perfectly with an exact copy of this DB created in my localhost, and prints a result when I run it locally.

On the other hand when I run it with the connection to the online DB, the program shows absolutely nothing, no window, no line, no error, just the terminal where I run it with a blank line, so i dont know where to start looking. The error reports are active, and show any other errors that happen.

Please,can anybody give me a hint on this?

Comment: Can you connect to your online DB through another client or the command line? That would at least narrow down whether it was your code, or the connection itself failing. MySQL has an option that you can set to make it ignore TCP traffic, so it's possible your online DB is not even listening for external (TCP) connection.

Comment: I tried with the terminal provided by google cloud and it works, but  ctually I wouldn't know how to do it from the ubuntu terminal, since I'm doing this to learn.  How can I do it from command line?

Comment: It's pretty easy. I assume that since you have ran the app locally, you have MySQL installed locally. And with that assumption, I also assume you have the mysql_client tools locally. Then just try connecting like this from a command (terminal) prompt: "mysql -h 104.xxx.xxx.xxx -u <username> -p<password>" NOTICE! There is NO SPACE after the "-p" and the password! There are plenty of Google hits on how to connect to MySQL from the command line, so you can check those out if you get stuck.

Comment: Note also that your user themselves ("root" in your case) can -- and usually is -- defined to only allow connections from localhost by default. If you're running this code on a VM out there, are you sure you don't just need to connect to localhost and not the IP itself?

Comment: @mrunion  ok, i just tried to connect, from terminal, using `mysql -h 104.197.112.189 -u root -p`, it requested my password, 
and then I get the same result as in the program. Nothing happens, What does it mean?

Comment: It means that there is something misconfigured with your online DB that it is not taking connections. You may need to create another user that can take outside requests, or there may be some settings that need changed to allow TCP connections. I don't know about the Google Cloud Platform, so I can't give you more instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that google cloud has a default firewall that must be configured to use almost anything, and that mariadb also has tcp connections blocked as default.

Thank you very much @mrunion for giving me some light, you were rightk, db and server were not listening.

I will edit the title and tags of the question, so it can help someone else, and post any result I get later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for someone with a similar problem, Mariadb (probably also works for MySQL) and Google Cloud have all external connections locked by default. It can be solved in two steps:

In google cloud: going into the developer console/ your project/ connections/ firewall rules and create a new rule allowing port 3306, that is default for MySQL and Mariadb.

In Mariadb: change `my.conf`, following the first part of [this tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/).
And that's it, now it's working. Thanks to @mrunion for the help.